# Walter Lewin's physics lecture 8.03 Waves and Oscillation

Tags: waves, specific-reference, oscillators

Does any of you have the files (lecture notes, assignments, exams) of Walter Lewin's course on Waves and Oscillations? I used to learn from them and it helped so much. Thanks before

Comment: I'm voting to close because we are not a file-sharing service, though I don't know how much precedence there is on this. We'll see what the rest of the community says.

Comment: MIT OpenCourseWare has removed all the video links of Prof. Lewin's classes due to his involvement in some harrasment case.

Comment: I can suggest you to read the book written by another MIT Prof. A.P. French.

Comment: His lectures are still available on youtube.

Comment: The Archive might help you: https://web.archive.org/web/20140722231615/http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-03-physics-iii-vibrations-and-waves-fall-2004/lecture-notes/.

Comment: @ChrisWhite It should be noted, though, that the lectures were previously freely distributed by MIT OCW, so this is not a clear cut case of copyright infringement per se (but as mentioned by other commentators, are no longer available as MIT wanted to distance itself from the professor). The lectures were of exceptional quality and I do hope they resurface in some official form.

Comment: @alarge: I don't think the copyright is the issue here, as this site is a question & answer site. This "question" contains no physics concept and answers to the post would be links (which are usually not well-received answers network-wide).

Comment: I would open this. Taken as a precedent, it is not asking for a recommendation of a good book, which we would close. It is asking for a specific source which as become difficult to get. It is on topic because it is lectures on physics. It is an unusual case, so we would be making something of an exception to close or keep it open. Taken as an individual case, it seems worthwhile.

Comment: Typing "Walter Lewin Lectures" into Google gave me lots of hits to live links to the lectures. For example, http://videolectures.net/mit803f04_physics_vibrations/

Comment: @alarge I'm aware of the backstory. As Kyle Kanos said, it's an issue of whether we become a "please give me this file" site, copyright and lecture quality aside. This can always be brought up on [Meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/) for further discussion.